# Is it possible for topological dynamical systems to be semiconjugate if one of the dynamical systems is minimal but the other one is not?

Tags: dynamical-systems

Is it possible for topological dynamical systems to be semiconjugate if one of the dynamical systems is *minimal* but the other one is not? (*minimal* means every orbit of the dynamical system is dense)
If so, is there any simple example of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is certainly possible. One of the best known examples is the Denjoy construction. Full details of this construction are given in [Milnor's notes](http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~jack/DYNOTES/dn15.pdf), section 15B, under the title "Denjoy counterexamples". Let me give a brief outline.

Start with an irrational rotation of the circle $f : S^1 \to S^1$, $f(z) = e^{2\pi i \theta}z$ where $\theta$ is irrational. This map $f$ is minimal.

Pick an orbit, say $A = \{z_n \mid n \in \mathbb Z\}$ where $z_n = e^{2 \pi i \theta n}$. Pick a bi-infinite convergent sequence of reals $(\ell_n)_{n=-\infty}^\infty$, $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \ell_n = 1$.

You then cut open $S^1$ at each point $e^{2\pi i \theta n} \in A$, and insert an open interval $I_n$ of length $\ell_n$ between the resulting two points (Milnor explains what happens with those two points carefully). The resulting space $X$, with the obvious circular ordering, is homeomorphic to the circle. The union of the open intervals $I_n$ is an open subset $W \subset X$, and its complement $X-W$ is a Cantor set.

You then define $\tilde f : X \to X$ to be the homeomorphism that takes each $I_n$ to $I_{n+1}$ by the obvious similarity map of expansion factor $\ell_{n+1} / \ell_n$. This map $\tilde f$ is not minimal, because the union of the $I_n$'s is a wandering set. Also, the map $X \mapsto S^1$ which collapses (the closure of) each $I_n$ back to the point $z_n$ is a semiconjugacy from $\tilde f$ to $f$.

As a side note, the map $\tilde f$ takes the Cantor set $X-W$ to itself, and the restricted map $\tilde f : X-W \to X-W$ is minimal.

Comment: Thank you. I think there's a typo, it should be the map $f$ is minimal?

Comment: Actually it wasn't a typo, but it was confusing, and I rewrote that part.

Comment: Come to think of it, couldn't we get a simpler example by considering an irrational rotation and the one sided shift map on the set, $S$ say,of infinite binary sequences?  The semi-conjugacy would then be the map from $S$ to the circle which we identify with the interval $I=[0, 1]$.  The semi conjugacy can then map each binary sequence $(x_n) \in S$ to the number $x\in I$ with binary expansion given by $(x_n)$.

Comment: I just noticed that this doesn't work... the defined semi conjugacy fails to be one.